# Separate (second) WordPress taxonomy template

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

Struggling for days. Therefore reaching out to SO praying for directions.

1. We have a WooCommerce store. With multiple categories.
2. We have a custom post type `questions` with the Woo `product_cat` taxonomy assigned to it. To put questions into categories.

```
register_post_type('questions', array(
    ...
    'taxonomies' => array('product_cat'),
    ...
));
```

3. The `archive-questions.php` and the `single-questions.php` page are working fine.

**Q:** How can we show questions filtered by product category?

We cannot make use of `taxonomy-product_cat.php` template as that is already been uses for Woo to show the products.

Comment: *"We would like to have a page were we can show our knowledge base articles for a product category"* seems to me you would need a custom page. Yes it's possible!

Comment: @Ruvee I agree. But how can we achieve such pages? Any idea how?